# Is it possible to run JavaFx without X-server?

Tags: javafx, raspbian, xserver

My plan is to run a JavaFx application on a Raspberry Pi. While the usual way is to start the GUI which is then redirected to the HDMI port, which presents the whole of desktop on the TV.

However, I do not want to see the desktop or anything else, other than the content rendered by my application on the TV. Is it possible to send the rendered output directly to HDMI port?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need the arm port of java8, where fx renders directly into the framebuffer.

Comment: Do you mean Java 8? I do not see any ARM port for Java 7.

Comment: Right sorry mixed that up with the java7 one for beagleboard.

Comment: Then can you please fix your post? I cannot edit your post since stupid SO needs that I edit at least 6 characters.